Nature of polynomials that are satisfied by a $n\times n$ matrix with degree greater than $n$
We all are very familiar with the fact that minimal polynomial and characteristics polynomial of a matrix is satisfied by the matrix itself.
Now, I am stuck while doing this.
a) If $A \in M(3,\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^4=I ,A \neq \pm I $ then $A^2+I=0.$ (True/False)
b) If $A \in M(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^3=I ,A \neq \pm I $ then $A^2+A+I=0.$ (True/False)
c) If $A \in M(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^3=I$ and $A^t=A$ then $A^2+A+I=0.$ ($A^t$ is transpose of A) (True/False)
My approach is for any polynomial $p(t)$ satisfied by the matrix, the minimal polynomial $m_A(t) \mid p(t)$.
Thus $p(t)$ will contain all of the eigenvalues as roots. If $p(t)$ is characteristic polynomial then it will have all of the eigenvalues (counted with multiplicities) as roots.
For option a) the matrix $A$ will certainly satisfy a polynomial $p(t)=t^4-t=t(t^3-1).$
Simple observation is that $(t^3-1)$ will be the characteristic polynomial. Hence it will have only $1$ as real eigenvalue. I can't proceed further.

a) is false.
Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
c) is false.
Take $A = I$.
b) is true.
The minimal polynomial $m_A(t)$ of $A$ must be a divisor of $t^3 - 1$ since $A^3 = I$. We have $t^3 - 1 = (t-1)(t^2+t+1)$, where $t^2+t+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[t]$. Thus either $m_A(t) = t - 1$ or $m_A(t) = t^2+t+1$. The first case is impossible because $A \ne I$. Thus $m_A(t) = t^2+t+1$ and $A^2 + A + I = 0$.
Update.
No matrix $A \in M(3,\mathbb R)$ satisfies $A^2 + I = 0$.
Assume that $A$ satisfies $A^2 + I = 0$. Then the minimal polynomial $m_A(t)$ of $A$ must be a divisor of $t^2 + 1$ since $A^2 + I = 0$. Since $t^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[t]$, we have $m_A(t) = t^2 + 1$. The characteristic polynomial $p_A(t)$ of $A$ has degree $3$ and is divisible by $m_A(t)$. Hence $p_A(t) = (t^2 + 1) (t - a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$.
We can regard $A$ as a complex matrix $A \in M(3,\mathbb C)$. It has the $3$ distinct eigenvalues $a, i, -i$, thus it is diagonalizable. This means that there exists $P \in GL(3,\mathbb C)$ such that $PAP^{-1} = B := \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \end{pmatrix}$. This implies
$$0 = P(A^2 + I)P^{-1} = PAP^{-1}PAP^{-1} + I = B^2 +I .
$$
This is impossible because $B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.
